# Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. GradientStop

Tags: wpf

I have a list box contains Colors and Each Color have 7 Heads it is to choose Print Head for Color. so my Binding variable is when print head is  selected , Color box should have this Styles.

```
<Setter TargetName="colorSelectionRectangle" Property="Fill">
 <Setter.Value>
     <LinearGradientBrush SpreadMethod="Repeat" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="25,25">
         <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
             <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01" />
         </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
         <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White" />
         <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White" />
         <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{Binding [0].Item.PrintColor.Argb}" />
         <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding [0].Item.PrintColor.Argb}" />
     </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Setter.Value>
```

and My error is  :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=[0].Item.PrintColor.Argb; DataItem=null; target element is 'GradientStop' (HashCode=52327179); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Comment: Can you provide some more details? For instance the actual element you are styling and the nature of the model used in the binding.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have this problem because `GradientStop` is *not* a `FrameworkElement`... from MSDN:

```
System.Object 
  System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject
    System.Windows.DependencyObject
      System.Windows.Freezable
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Animatable
          System.Windows.Media.GradientStop
```

If you notice the extended `System.Windows.Freezable` class above, then you will see that this class is also 'freezable'... this means that it cannot be modified. See the [Freezable Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx) page at MSDN for more information.